# Are these two statements involving inf and sup equivalent?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space. Is

> $$\inf_{h \in H}\sup_{g \in H}\frac{f(h,g)}{|h||g|} \geq C$$

the same as

> $$f(h,h) \geq C|h|^2\quad \forall h \in H$$

?
Here $f\colon H \times H \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and linear and $|h|$ means the norm of $h$. Or does the first imply the second?

Comment: I think you mean that $f$ is **bi**linear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second inequality implies the first. This is because
$$sup_{g\in H}\frac{f(h,g)}{|h||g|}\geq \frac{f(h,h)}{|h||h|}\geq C$$
and taking the infimum over all $h$ gives the first inequality. However, the first inequality doesn't imply the second. For example, take the function $f$ defined by the matrix 
$$ f((x,y),(a,b))=(x,y)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
 a\\
b
\end{array}\right)$$
Then $f((x,y),(x,y))=0$ for all vectors so that in the second inequality the only possibility for $C$ is 0. On the other hand, you have 
$$\frac{f( (x,y),(-y,x) )}{x^2+y^2}=1$$ so that in the first inequality you can choose $C=1$.